# Use Mathematica to draw a tensor-like network

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, image, tensors

What are the Mathematica ways to draw this seemly delicate figure? Such that we can output a PDF file in the end.

[image]

Comment: The underlying grid can be composed with `Line`. The vertices can be labeled with `Point` in the first case, the centroids can be computed and labeled with `Point` and then connected by `Line` in the third case, and can be labeled with `Rectangle` and partially connected in the second case.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks +1 that helps!